# Python get info about group policy

Tags: python, python-2.7, group-policy

I'm making a program in PYTHON  that gives some info about the computer, and a part of it is to get info about the Group Policy - Password Policy (The Full path in gpedit.msc is :
*Local Computer Policy >> Cumputer Configuration >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Account Policy >> **Password Policy & Account Lockout Policy**.*

I need a way to get info about them both in python...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Something like this perhaps: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command with administrator:

> secedit /export /cfg group-policy.inf /log export.log

In python:

> os.system('secedit /export /cfg  group-policy.inf /log export.log')

All info will be exported to group-policy.inf file and then parse the file will get the info you want.

See [secedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490997.aspx) command.

Comment: In CMD it sure does work but on python i need to retrieve this info with just regular permissions... So it's not so helpful... But thanks anyway!

Comment: And another question..  How do I manage to achieve just the fields I want in the export log... ?